# specify long name space and dynamic parameters

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, cloudwatch-alarms

i want to create new alarms on my resource metrics.
the problem is that the metric name is the same but under a different sub name space.
i know how to specify the general Namespace like: AWS/ECS or something like that.

but in my case the metrics name are with same name under a general name space:
the first: AWS/ECS > X > Y -> metric name = M
the second: AWS/ECS > Z > W -> metric name = M.

how can i specify correctly the full name space in the yaml?.

the second problem is that the alarm threshold differs from environment to environment and it's not static. i know i can create parameter with multiple allowed values but i have 5 allowed values and i want to assign them based on the environment var that is given.
i tried a couple of times with `Condition` but it's not working for me some how.
what is the best when to assign the dynamic threshold?.

Comment: Can you show some relevant template snippets and why the don't work, what errors you get why you try?

Comment: i dont have a snippet because i didnt find a appropriate solution. i need to construct a nested if/else statement that will determine the value of my threshold. regarding my first question the situation is that for both of the metrics the global namespace is `Namespace: AWS/DynamoDB` and the metric name is the same. how can i specify the full namespace in order to get the metric i want?